# Upgrading from EF Core 3.1 to EF Core 6.0

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Post upgrading from EF Core 3.1 to EF Core 6.0 we started facing the following issue:

*The association between entity types 'Table1' and 'Table2' has been severed, but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the relationship to use cascade deletes.*

Ideally following is the pseudo code

```
delete rows from table2 (1 row removed)
re-add rows to table2 (1 row added)

delete rows from table 1 (throws the above error)
re-add rows to table1
```

Note:
Till this point we are doing the above steps in in-memory (i.e. commit will happen post re-add (if any) happens to table1).

The above steps (in the pseudo code) were working just fine with EF Core 3.1.

Are there any changes in terms of 'Delete.Behavior' on EF Core 3.1 vs EF Core 6.0?

Comment: My first guess is that it has to do with nullable reference types. Check your entities and add a question mark at the navigation properties

Comment: `class Customer { public Contact? Contact { get; set; } }`

Comment: Yes, that's a great thought! Just had few follow up questions on this one:                  How come it was working in ef core3.1, just wondering if the behavior has changed with EF core 6.0.                                                                    Also, if a user is having database with older schema, by changing the navigation properties to nullable(?) how much impact this would have!

Comment: I don't think your change will modify the database schema inbetween. In your .NET 3.1 state the properties are nullable by default (reference types are always nullable). .NET 6 changed this and reference types are "considered" non-nullable now (not enforced yet). So by adding the `?` your properties are still nullable. So nothing changes. But I guess EF6 does in fact look at it